# Explain me about this simple ruby code

Tags: ruby

I'm newbie in Ruby. What is printed and why?

```
a = nil
b = 2
a ||= b
puts a
```

explain me about this simple code.

Comment: a ||= b is short hand for a = a || b since a is nil (and falsy) b will printed which is 2.  just open up irb and try it yourself.

Comment: This isn't really a Ruby question, it's basic programming logic that applies to all languages. A good programming text book will cover it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of programming requires understanding Boolean logic, basically how true and false values are determined, which are what trigger conditional logic to branch, loop, etc.

Consider this:

In Ruby there are true and false values, which have equivalent reserved words of `true` and `false` (it actually goes deeper than this but that's for a different time.):

```
true # => true
false # => false
```

Only `nil` and `false` are false values in Ruby, everything else is `true`. This differs from some other languages, like Perl, which thinks that `0` and `''` (empty string) are also false. Remember though, only `nil` and `false` in Ruby are false.

The "not" values (AKA, opposites) of `true` and `false` are `false` and `true` respectively. The `!` (Boolean "NOT") operator is used for this:

```
!true # => false
!false # => true
```

Now, this is a trick you'll see advanced programmers use: NOT-ing them twice returns a boolean version of their original values:

```
!!true # => true
!!false # => false
```

This is an important thing to understand. We can use `!!` on values besides `true`/`false` and determine whether they are true or false values:

```
!!'' # => true # !> string literal in condition
!!0 # => true # !> literal in condition
!!'foo' # => true # !> string literal in condition
!!1 # => true # !> literal in condition
```

Ruby isn't too happy about me using a literal for the test, but you can see that the above are all true, and these are false:

```
!!false # => false
!!nil # => false
```

Hopefully you see how we have to look at values in a language two ways, whether they're true/false and what their actual value is.

Moving on:

The `||` (Boolean "OR") looks at the left value first. If it's true it returns that value. If it's false, it looks at the right side and returns that:

```
true || false # => true
false || true # => true

nil || 'foo' # => "foo"
false || 2 # => 2
```

The `||=` operator behaves similarly, only after the comparison, it *assigns* to the variable on the left if it was a false-type value:

```
a = false
a ||= true
a # => true

a = true
a ||= false
a # => true
```

Assigning to variables, instead of testing directly against the literals, results in similar results:

```
a = nil  # => nil
!a # => true
!!a # => false

b = 2 # => 2
!b # => false
!!b # => true
```

A bit more:

`||=` is used as shorthand to replace a little bit of `if`/`then` code:

```
a = nil  # => nil
b = 2    # => 2
if !a
  a = b
end
a # => 2

a = 1    # => 1
b = 2    # => 2
if !a
  a = b
end
a # => 1
```

And all that leads up to the code you're trying to understand:

```
a = nil  # => nil
b = 2    # => 2
a ||= b  # => 2
```

Answer (score 2):

`2` is printed, because `||=` assigns the right-hand value to the left-hand variable when the left-hand variable is `nil` or `false`. `a` is `nil`, so `2` will be assigned to `a`. Therefore `2` is printed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `||=` is a shorthand way of saying "if `a` is false assign it to..." in this case `b`

So

```
a = nil
b = 2
a ||= b
puts a
  > 2
```

and

```
a = 4
b = 2
a ||= b
puts a
  > 4
```

Comment: It's not saying "if a is nil", it's saying "if a is false". In Ruby, nil and `false` are false values, everything else is `true`.